# Copying external Excel range into memory

Tags: excel, vba

I have an external excel spreadsheet which I want to open to get a range, copy this into memory and close the source workbook.

The code I have to test this looks like this:

```
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(sWkbSourcePath)
Set rngList = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("rgnList")

Debug.Print "The original:" & rngList.Cells(1, 2) & " is a " & rngList.Cells(1, 1)

rngList.Copy Destination:=rngCopy

wkbSource.Close

Debug.Print "The copy:" & rngCopy.Cells(1, 2) & " is a " & rngCopy.Cells(1, 1)
Debug.Print "---END---"
```

The second debug print does nothing. Instead of

```
 rngList.Copy Destination:=rngCopy
```

I also tried this

```
 rngCopy.value = rngList.value
```

and I tried to store the value of the range in variant.

None of this works. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you to both for your answers. I was hoping to find a way to copy a range as an object which is not tied to any part of a sheet, but on which I can call range, find, etc... 
I thought that this may not be possible and you guys confirmed that.

Comment: The "problem" is that a Range is not an independent object. It "lives" in a Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

When copying Range object, you should specify another Range object as destination. In other case, range will be copied into Clipboard.

```
Destination   Optional Variant. Specifies the new range to which the specified range will be copied. If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel copies the range to the Clipboard.

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").Copy _
    destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5")
```

In your code you passing empty variable, so, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming named range **rngList** is defined in source workbook, and consistent with the definition of **rngCopy**

```
Option Explicit
Sub a()
Dim r, rngCopy As Range
Dim wkbSource As Workbook

Set rngCopy = Range("A1:D8")
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("c:\mata.xls")
Set r = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("rngList")

Debug.Print "The original:" & r.Cells(1, 2) & " is a " & r.Cells(1, 1)

r.Copy Destination:=rngCopy
wkbSource.Close

Debug.Print "The copy:" & rngCopy.Cells(1, 2) & " is a " & rngCopy.Cells(1, 1)
Debug.Print "---END---"

End Sub
```